# iPad PDF print size issue

Tags: ipad, pdf

We have developed the application to generate pdf from iPad & it is working fine.

The issue is, when I print the PDF from some iPAD, it is printing perfectly.

But for some iPADs, the print size got zoomed out (it is reducing the size to 90-95%).

Could you please advice what could be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed any difference between the iPads? IN iPad 3 with retina display it increases size of low resolution images and all automatically but ipad without retina doesnt do that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the difference in size I would say that some of your iPads print the PDF using no scaling, while the others pring the PDF using a fit to printable area scaling mode.

Comment: There is no option to scaling the PDF in iPAD.